# How to bind a LabelMorph/TextMorph to a variable so that the Morph reflects changes of the variable?

Tags: user-interface, smalltalk, pharo, squeak, morphic

- I have an object with a variable containing a String.
- I have a window containing a LabelMorph/TextMorph (or some other Morph that displays Text?).

How do i bind the LabelMorph/TextMorph to the variable, so that the label updates when the String in the variable changes?

- classic Smalltalk-80 dependent/change/update mechanism?
- Pharo Announcement framework?
- something different??

How would i do this? Which Morph should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to achieve.
You might want to take a look at a way to do it with Glamour in a current Moose image.
In a workspace, do-it:

```
GLMBasicExamples new magritte openOn: GLMMagrittePersonExample sampleData
```

That shows how to work with announcements on save. The earlier examples are a better way to start understanding how to work with Glamour (and because of the way the examplebrowser is build, the Magritte example doesn't update the list when it is nested):

```
GLMBasicExamples open
```

That has several other examples that update on change.

Comment: Thank you, i start studying documentation and examples. This is very interesting.

Answer (score 7):

Simplest is to use an updating String morph:

```
UpdatingStringMorph on: self selector: #myLabel
```

This will send #myLabel (or any other message) to self (or any other object) and display it.

Comment: This works well and i didn't know it existed. But it uses the #step method of the Morph to ask for changes each step. Do you also know what a more "observer-pattern-like" solution could look like?

Comment: You can use any of the frameworks, but nothing beats the simplicity of the Morphic stepping mechanism. This is how Morphic is intended to be used.

Comment: Seems, i can only accept one answer. Feel both accepted and i voted both answers up :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution provided by Benjamin Van Ryseghem on the Pharo Mailinglist:

> For this kind of situation, my solution is to use a ValueHolder.
>   Instead of storing your string directly in an instance variable, store
>   it into the ValueHolder.

I tried this in a Workspace:

```
|string label|

string := 'Wait till i change..' asValueHolder.
label := LabelMorph contents: string contents.
string whenChangedDo: [:newValue | label contents: newValue ].
label openInWindow.
[ 5 seconds asDelay wait. string value: 'I changed :)' ] fork.
```