# Changing Smalltalk Pharo TextMorph contents dynamically

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Is there any way to retrieve the TextMorph added to a StandardWindow in Pharo and then change its text contents?

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve the contents of a `SystemWindow` or it's subclass, a `StandardWindow` by sending it the `paneMorphs` or `paneMorphSatisfying:` message.

You can set the contents of a TextMorph via - `contents:` :)

Evaluate this example line by line in a Workspace or Playground and observe the text in the window:

```
| textMorph text1 text2 window |
textMorph := TextMorph new.
text1 := 'Smalltalk is cool' asText.
text2 := 'Pharo is cool' asText.
textMorph contents: text1.
window := textMorph openInWindow.
window paneMorphs first contents: text2.
```

Here we have only one paneMorph, the textMorph. In a more complicated layout, you have to choose the right paneMorph first. Or you would keep a reference to your textMorph in the first place, and would not have to retrieve it from the window...

Comment: Thank you thats pretty helpful. I have like 4 textmorphs in my window. By keeping references to the textmorphs, did you mean save it as instance variables in the class?

Comment: Also, is there a way to dynamically update them? Like if I assign the contents: aVariable to a Smalltalk variable and then update the variable, is it possible that my TextMorph content changes with it?

Comment: @ruhimehta Yes exactly, keeping a variable to the morph you want to access again later.

Comment: @ruhimehta You should have a look at the Glamour or Spec framework. Also I remember posting a similar question once: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15534305/2012262 Have a look at the answers there.